# Read Netcdf sub categories and convert to grid

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I also posted this question on stack gis [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170597/reading-netcdf-sub-variables-and-convert-to-raster-grid-in-r). From the netcdf4 data that have sub categories, I want to be able to read `"Retrieval/fs"` variable. I also want to read them and convert to raster girds, but it seems that raster doesn't support netcdf4. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
file <- "http://140906_B7101Ar_150909171225s.nc4"

names(file$var)
"latitude" ... "longitude"... "Retrieval/fs"

lat <- raster(file, varname="latitude")
lon <- raster(file, varname="longitude")

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"ncdf4"’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question I asked. Since the data is not gridded, I retrieve the lon and lat information along with the variables to create a dataframe.

```
fs <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "Retrieval/fs")
xlon <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "longitude")
xlat <- ncvar_get(ncfile, "latitude")
d <- data.frame( as.vector(xlon),as.vector(xlat), as.vector(fs))# create a dataframe
coordinates(d) <- c("xlon","xlat")
proj4string(d) <- CRS("+proj=longlat") 
spoint <- SpatialPoints(coords = d) #create a spatial point object
```

Answer (score 3):

`raster` does work with `ncdf4` You are now showing actual code. `file` is a character vector. You cannot do `names(file$var)` with that (at least you won't get "latitude" ... "longitude"... "Retrieval/fs". So `file` is probably `ncdf4` object (see the error message), while the `raster` function expects a filename (but not a url).

If you download the file and then do

```
library(raster)
x <- brick(filename, var="Retrieval/fs")
```

Things should work *if* the ncdf file had regular raster data.

However, it does not so you cannot directly import this as a raster. Instead you can get the lat and lon and values from the files, treat these as points and then rasterize (interpolate) these to get a regular raster.

Comment: yes, these are not rasterized. I need to interpolate points, but the problem is I can't read the `Retrieval/fs` variable.