# Error while converting netcdf data into a raster brick

Tags: r, stack, raster, ncdf4

I'm trying to visualize monthly averages of RegCM output I joined using CDO but I'm not being able to do it.

In order to do that I was trying to find a way to plot de monthly averages of my variable "pr" as you could do using GrADS.

I found that a way to do this was using the brick function and the raster library. So I was trying to use the code suggested in another question to convert my netcdf file into a raster brick:
[NetCDF to Raster Brick "Unable to find inherited method for function 'brick' for 'ncdf4'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982599/netcdf-to-raster-brick-unable-to-find-inherited-method-for-function-brick-for/43244622#comment74389320_43244622)

```
# load package
 library(sp)
 library(raster)
 library(ncdf4)

 # read ncdf file
 nc<-nc_open('dat.nc')

 # extract variable name, size and dimension
 v <- nc$var[[1]]
 size <- v$varsize
 dims <- v$ndims
 nt <- size[dims]              # length of time dimension
 lat <- nc$dim$xlat$vals   # latitude position
 lon <- nc$dim$xlong$vals  # longitude position

 # read pr variable
 r<-list()
 for (i in 1:nt) {
   start <- rep(1,dims)     # begin with start=(1,1,...,1)
   start[dims] <- i             # change to start=(1,1,...,i) to read    timestep i
   count <- size                # begin with count=(nx,ny,...,nt), reads entire var
   count[dims] <- 1             # change to count=(nx,ny,...,1) to read 1 tstep

   dt<-ncvar_get(nc, varid = 'pr', start = start, count = count)

   # convert to raster
   r[i]<-raster(dt)
 }

 # create layer stack with time dimension
 r<-stack(r)

 # transpose the raster to have correct orientation
 rt<-t(r)
 extent(rt)<-extent(c(range(lon), range(lat)))

 # plot the result
 spplot(rt)
```

But once I tried to run the for loop in the code, I get the following error:

```
Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  Error: variable has 3 dims, but start has 2 entries.  They must match!
```

The file I'm trying to visualize can be found in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13KsOpnt-Wk2v93WwGcOU6AHw8KGOFlai/view?usp=sharing

I would really appreciate any insights with this problem!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think you'll find doing this in `terra`, `sf` the way to go and best pipeline for going forward. [Evolution of R spatial](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10109-020-00336-0), plenty of `terra` & `netcdf` ?s now on Stackoverflow and gis.Stackexchange... Will look at your data after dog walk.

Comment: Writing your 1st question on S.O. is tough, may I suggest that your title explain your goal or purpose not just an error message. Bad title: android if else problems; Good title: Why does str == "value" evaluate to false when str is set to "value"? And consider, Introducing your problem before you post any code. Not everyone has the talent to read minds. ;) Consider re-writing parts or adding more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the insights! I'll read the documentation you suggest and try to modify my R script

Comment: @mccurcio I tried to edit the post in order to make it clearer, I hope It's better now.